# jquery ajax with query string invoking at server side not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

In my application I have used jquery ajax and this ajax call invokes some method at server side. In this method I have code which grabs the query strings and based on the query string value it processes the data. I am using below lines of code to get query string.

```
    var MyajaxCall = function () {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "OneCol.aspx/SingleData",
            data: JSON.stringify({DptID:1}),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                jsonData = msg.d;
            },
            Error: function (x, e) {
                alert("Some error");
            }
        });
    };
```

C# code

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string SingleData(string DptID)
    {
        OneTestPage onpage = new OneTestPage ();
        return onpage.GetString();
    }

    private string GetString() 
    {
        return Request.QueryString["test"].ToString();
    }
```

Everytime my ajax request hits this line of code I am getting "Request is not available in this context". Is this because data is not ready yet this time ? if so what is the best way to get it work.

Comment: Is this mvc? We need to see your jquery and controller methods. Please publish all relevant codes when asking questions.

Comment: You are creating a new instance of OneTestPage inside that static method and HttpContext is not bound to this new instance hence the error. Does the web method have to be static? Either change it to an instance method, or in the GetString method, return HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["test"].ToString(); (Not recommended)

Comment: If I am not wrong web method have to be static otherwise wont be able to access it from jquery ajax

Comment: Then, the only solution is to get the query string parameter by HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["test"];. I also need to say, you will not be able to access any of the page elements. Please change the GetString() method to be static and inside, use HttpContext.Current.Request, and remove new OneTestPage(). We should never create Page instances like this anyway.